# Best way to do leave 1 out indexing in numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, indexing, slice

I am trying to figure out the best way to do leave one out indexing with numpy, this is the desired behaviour:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.randint(0,10,size=10)
print(a)

def fun(x, xs):
    print(x,xs) #do some stuff

for i in range(a.shape[0]):
    fun(a[i], a[np.arange(a.shape[0]) != i]) #this is all I can think of, but its horrid!
```

is there a nicer, more efficient way to do this?

EDIT: To clarify, a question that is hopefully a bit clearer:

I have an array and I want a view that has 1 or more elements missing in the *middle* e.g. `a = [1,2,3,4,5,...]` to `a = [1,2,4,5,...]`. According to [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/indexing-in-numpy/) fancy indexing / masking makes a copy of the array, I want to avoid this, and avoid creating a large index array. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: depends what `fun` does. You might get away with setting the element to `nan` for a sum/average

Comment: That forces a copy with `a[np.arange(a.shape[0]) != i]`. Can you slice and work in two stages - `a[:i]` and `a[i+1:]`? These would be views and hence could be better.

Comment: You could use a masked array, and move the masked element one over every time, or just pass in the index instead of the slice. If you are very lucky, all of `fun` can be properly vectorized, and you won't need the loop at all.

Comment: Point is, it's very difficult to help without knowing more.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I gave the function as some arbitrary example, but really I am asking if its possible to create a view - a combination of `a[:i] a[i+1:]` as @Divakar suggested.

Comment: Would your function accept the second arg as the higher dim array? If so, would `fun(a[i], a[:i])` and `fun(a[i], a[i+1:])` work? It's just two steps and no loop.

Comment: so `np.append(a[:i], a[i+1:])` ?

Comment: @TopherBuckley this will create a copy of `a[:i]` which is not going to be efficient.

Comment: Either you make a copy, or you work with two `views`.  There's no way of making one `view` with a gap in the middle.

Comment: @hpaulj is there a reason why this is not supported? I haven't found anything about it after quite a bit of searching.

Comment: A `view` differs from the original in just 2 parameters, `shape` and `strides` (ok there may be a data buffer pointer difference as well).  You may need to read up on `strides`, and how those are used to iterate (in C code) through the array.  Your gap case cannot be expressed as a stride.  http://scipy-lectures.org/advanced/advanced_numpy/#indexing-scheme-strides

Comment: I know I'm way out of my league here, and have no idea what is making a copy in the background or not, but just curious and using this as an excuse to go through the numpy docs in more detail. What about this? 

`np.roll(np.roll(a, -i)[1:], i))`

I.e. rolling to make the index you want omitted to index 0, taking a slice of [1:], then rolling back to the original order. Would this make any copies? 
How do you check if it is making copies? I'd be happy to look further if you can explain how to verify this is doing what you want, i.e. what test of efficiency are you looking to see as proof?

Comment: This was something that I had considered, however unfortunately `roll` does create a copy of the array (although it is not very clear from the docs).  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35916201/alternative-to-numpy-roll-without-copying-array). Thank you for the suggestion either way!